# No encoder has been configured for account Symfony2.6

Tags: php, symfony

I've tried to add a basic authentification service to my website. I get a "No encoder has been configured for account" when I try to log in.

I use the "Visiteur" entity, which looks like this :

```
namespace WilsonCorp\Bundle\Comptabilite\FraisBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * Visiteur
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="WilsonCorp\Bundle\Comptabilite\FraisBundle\Entity\VisiteurRepository")
 */
class Visiteur implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{

 [...]

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=20)
 */
private $password;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $salt;


public function eraseCredentials()
{
}

public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->id,
    ));
}

public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list (
        $this->id,
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
}
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->fichesFrais = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
}
```

My security.yml :

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_COMPTABLE: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_COMPTABLE]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH, ROLE_COMPTABLE]

    providers:
        ddbUsers:
            entity: { class: WilsonCorpComptabiliteFraisBundle:Visiteur, property: username}

    firewalls:
        main_login:
            pattern: ^/login$
            anonymous: true
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: false
            provider: ddbUsers
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login_check
            logout:
                path: logout
                target: /
```

Am I missing something ? Is there any tweak to do in the Visiteur controller ?

I've tried adding the lines

```
    encoders:
        WilsonCorp\Comptabilite\FraisBundle\Entity\Visiteur: md5
```

But it does not do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, the db field for password wasn't big enough for the encrypted password.

My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `WilsonCorp\Bundle\Comptabilite\FraisBundle\Entity\Visiteur` instead of `WilsonCorp\Comptabilite\FraisBundle\Entity\Visiteur` as the key of your encoders setting.

Comment: I've also tried this : the error is gone but then my credentials aren't recognized anymore.

Comment: @TazMayhem that's another question and has probably something to do with not encoding the credentials submitted with the login form